# What is the correct terminology for this array literal of struct literals?

Tags: c

I recently ran into this method of declaring an array of structs, but could find any documentation on it anywhere since I don't know what to search for. **What is this called?** -and/or- **Where is this syntax documented?**

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

// This right here:
static struct point points[3] = {
    [0] = { .x = 1, .y = 2 },
    [2] = { .x = 4, .y = 2 },
    [1] = { .x = 0, .y = 3 },
};
```

*(My apologies if this is the wrong place to post this kind of question.)*

Comment: It is called *designated initialization*. And is documented as anything else in C - in the C standard.

Comment: See [Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) and _designated initializer_.

Comment: Appreciate this, thank you both! -- I had just never seen this before. I think this syntax really shines when used in conjunction with enum values as the array indices.

Comment: It's an invaluable addition in C99 — that I can't use at work because the code also has to be compiled by MSVC and that hasn't supported it.  I suppose MSVC might support it in recent versions, but I'm constrained to use antique (if not prehistoric) versions.

Comment: Judging from MSVC 2022 documentation on [Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializers?view=msvc-170), MSVC still does not allow designated initializers — holding the rest of the world hostage to an antiquated standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just pasted OP's code into my VS2019 IDE and compiled (as C) with the Standard set to "Legacy" and it worked! (I added a short `main` to print out some of the structure array member values, just to be sure...)

Comment: ... doesn't work using the VS2010 toolset, though. :(

Comment: @AdrianMole — Thank you for that information.  Did I manage to miss something while scanning the documentation?  But that is good news.

Comment: @Jonathan meh... it's Microsoft documentation.

Comment: The page I linked to was for C++ rather than C.  The C [Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/initialization?view=msvc-170) pages don't mention designated initializers, not even on the [Initializing Aggregate Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/initializing-aggregate-types?view=msvc-170).  But it works.   Oh well!